# Strange issue. GET request is sent but where?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My web page has multiple ajax requests and all works OK and all of them sending POST requests. On one form (dynamically created by jQuery) I have a button (jQuery-ui). Just that button, nothing else.

On button I attached a click event handler. In that function I have ONLY `alert`. When I click on that button, the function is called and alert is displayed. BUT when I click OK on that `alert`, somehow I'm sending a GET request.

My web site is on URL: `http://localhost:9000/TestProjekat/main/`

After pressing OK on alert I'm getting: `http://localhost:9000/TestProjekat/main/?naziv=&pokrajina_drzava=-1`

Where this come from? I've searched everything... I have no ideas! Help please...

Comment: Is you button inside a form?

Comment: Yes button is inside form but form dont have url: it's like this: <form href="javascript:void(0)">. Is this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You button triggers the form that's why. You probably also didn't set the `method` attribute that's why it does a `GET`.
In your handler, do a `return false` or `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the default behaviour, your form won't get submitted.

Two ways :

```
$('#myBtn').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // to cancel the default behaviour
   // do stuff here
});
```

Or :

```
$('#myBtn').click(function (e) {
   // do stuff here
   return false; // to cancel the default behaviour
});
```

Comment: Now i figured out that form is problem.. I have putted method="POST" and now form sending post. But how to stop sending? I that function i put return false but nothing...